# UIAlertView, present modally for UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput

Tags: iphone, uialertview

So I want to present to the user an alert view for them to enter the password.  I'd like to check to make sure that something was entered at the keyboard.  I know in the UIAlertViewDelegate, you can get the text input.  However, the only solution I have so far is,

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSLog(@"buttonIndex: %i", buttonIndex);

    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        UITextField *passwordTextField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
        if (!passwordTextField.text.length == 0) {
            NSLog(@"password: %@", passwordTextField.text);
            // save the password
        }
        else {
            // Show the alert view again asking for the password
        }

    }

}
```

where I would ask for the password again right after they click ok if they didn't enter anything.  Is there a better solution to this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Present the alert view again. You can put the alert view in a method and call it.

```
...

} else {

    [self showPassAlert];

}
```

You can also watch for when the text field is edited, and enable/disable the button in the alert view. If the text field's length is 0, disable the button. When the text field is edited and its length is greater than 0, enable the button. This is more graceful than closing and reopening the view.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textDidChange) name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:textField];

...

-(void)textDidChange {

    for (UIView *view in alertView.subviews) {

        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {

            if (textField.text.length == 0) {

                //you may need to look for the button's title to make sure you are not disabling the cancel button

                ((UIButton *) view).enabled = NO;

            } else {

                ((UIButton *) view).enabled = YES;

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create `iboutlet`/reference for your UITextFields, which will aid you to retrieve its value at any moment of time.